# jQuery dialog: How to use?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I am learning how to use jQuery dialog. One link I found helpful is http://imperavi.com/redactor/examples/uidialog/. The code is listed below, but I don't know why it does not work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Test Dialog</title>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <p><a href="javascript:void(null);" onclick="showDialog();">Open</a></p>

  <div id="dialog-modal" title="Basic modal dialog" style="display: none;"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function showDialog()
    {
      $("#dialog-modal").dialog(
      {
        width: 600,
        height: 400,
        open: function(event, ui)
        {
          var textarea = $('<textarea style="height: 276px;">');
          $(textarea).redactor({
              focus: true,
              autoresize: false,
              initCallback: function()
              {
                  this.set('<p>Lorem...</p>');
              }
          });
        }
      });
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The dialog appears after adding jquery-ui and css, but *"Lorem..."* does not show.

One more thing... Is it possible to pass a string to "showDialog" such that it can show different content based on different link? For example, adding "Open 1" and "Open 2" to show different string?

Comment: Dialog is NOT part of the standard library but of the JQuery UI!
http://jqueryui.com/
You have to include that too. And do not forget to fetch a theme or it'll get very ugly. http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/

Comment: ... meaning you need to load it separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, you forgot to add jquery UI.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Test Dialog</title>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="path_to_jq_ui"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <p><a href="javascript:void(null);" onclick="showDialog('Lorem ipsum dolor');">Open</a></p>

  <div id="dialog-modal" title="Basic modal dialog" style="display: none;"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function showDialog(text)
    {
      $("#dialog-modal").html(text)
      $("#dialog-modal").dialog(
      {
        width: 600,
        height: 400,
        open: function(event, ui)
        {
          var textarea = $('<textarea style="height: 276px;">');
          $(textarea).redactor({
              focus: true,
              autoresize: false,
              initCallback: function()
              {
                  this.set('<p>Lorem...</p>');
              }
          });
        }
      });
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bY3F4/3/

Download JqueryUI from [here](http://jqueryui.com/)

**Edit:** Dynamic dialog content added to code

Answer (score 3):

[Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) is a part of [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/). You have to include it as well.

Answer (score 1):

the Dialog is in the JQuery UI, you only required the JQuery.
insert this in the beginning:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: you will also need the stylesheets or it will look awful :)

Comment: true that :) i just wanted to give idea, but actually i can see others did too :)

Answer (score 1):

Add jQuery UI Stylesheet

```
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Add jQuery + jQuery UI

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```